# Difference between RMI and Reflection

Tags: java

In our application we are using reflection to communicate between the process running on different JVM .

My understanding is even RMI is used to communicate between the process running on different JVM.

Question is what is the difference between these two technologies ?

Can I use RMI to call methods running on different JVM in same application?

Comment: reflection to communicate between 2 processes ? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) and [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) are two different things.

Reflection is the ability of a computer program to examine and modify the structure and behavior of the program at runtime.

RMI is a Java API that performs the object-oriented equivalent of remote procedure calls (RPC, inter-process communication)

Answer (score 0):

RMI is used to communicate between 2 different applications. One app calls a method from another app.
Reflection is used by an app to inspect classes and find out meta-data about them: like what methods are available, what fields, etc.

Reflection is not used for communication between processes. Maybe in your case is used to discover something about the remote process.

Comment: We are calling methods of different JVM via reflection. Is it not communication . Kindly correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, i suppose you could call with reflection methods on an remote object exposed with RMI.